# Data representation of largest DCT coefficients

Tags: discrete-signals, dct, compression

In many [examples](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/dct-for-speech-signal-compression.html) of data compression, we take the *S* *largest* coefficients of a signal in a sparse basis (eg. 1% of largest DCT coefficients) and set the rest to zero.

How do we practically represent the compressed signal? In the above example, once the smallest coefficients have been set to zero, the signal is directly converted back into the time domain and compared to the original. What if we wanted to store the data?

In other words, how do we concisely store the indexes of the zeroed out coefficients?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is very accurate. Storing only the value of the largest  (1 % for instance) coefficients, even  from a good sparsifying transform (DCT, wavelet, else) is fool's-gold, since you (more importantly the decoder) don't know where those coefficients are located.

And storing their binary indices could easily counterbalances the compression gain for the bare sparsification. Therefore some engineer trade-off should be found between theoretical optimal sparsity and actual practical storage. For images, in JPEG, a low-frequency to high-frequency parsing scheme (zig-zag) is used. After quantization, lots of zeroed-out coefficients are compacted with End-Of-block symbols.  In JPEG 2000, a multi-scale and bit-wise  path is often  used, and zeroed-out coefficients are compacted with EZW-SPIHT-like coding, that perform a sort of vector coding of zero bit-planes.

So, some pre-determined way of parsing coefficients, based on prior knowledge on the signal or image structure, is often useful for actual compression, and applicable to specific class of data.

Answer (score 4):

How is bit reduction achieved practically in JPEG?

First, the whole graylevel (8-bit per pixel) image is divided into adjacent blocks of 8 x 8 = 64 pixels. Then, each block is independently DCT transformed into 8 x 8 frequency coefficients $Q(u,v)$, and that is further weighted by a mask $W(u,v)$ which implements the **quantization**. This will set a lot of high frequency coefficients in $Q(u,v)$ to zero for a typical image. Whatever, then quantized coefficients are **zigzag** scanned (like a very long snake moving in the anti-diagonal of coefficients) and converted into a linear string of 64 quantized coefficients. Then this string is a variety of **run length** coded according to the number of zeros between evry two nonzero coeffcients. The last set of consecutive zeros define the end of block symbol EOB. The run length codes are then assigned a predesigned **Huffman** prefix VLC code. This forms the **bitstream** associated for a given block. Each block is independtly coded (except the DC level per block which are differentially coded from block to block). The RLC and Huffman coding stages performs the actual **bit reduction** mechanism, whereas Quantization stage performs the **information reduction**.